# Excel VBA Call Funtion (MAIN then many SUBs) :)

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to create a vba for my task. But I fear that it won't work and just return the message "procedure too large". So before I finish it (I was only at the 4 of 50 procedures I will do), I would want to know if there is a way I could divide my work, like use the "CALL" function.

But my problem is, I use the "FOR-NEXT" function, combined with the "IF-ELSE" function. Here is part of my code.

```
For R = 10 To LROW

If ws.Cells(R, 2).Value = "ASIA UNITED BANK" And ws.Cells(R, 3).Value = "C/A# 001-01-002838-0" Then
    ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Years & "-" & Months & "-" & Days
    ADD = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws1.Range("E2:E1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ws.Cells(R, 5).Value = ADD
    ws1.Cells.AutoFilter

    ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Years & "-" & Months & "-" & Days
    MIN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws1.Range("D2:D1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ws.Cells(R, 11).Value = MIN
    ws1.Cells.AutoFilter

ElseIf ws.Cells(R, 2).Value = "ASIA UNITED BANK" And ws.Cells(R, 3).Value = "C/A# 001-01-003813-3" Then
    ws2.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Years & "-" & Months & "-" & Days
    ADD = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws2.Range("E2:E1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ws.Cells(R, 5).Value = ADD
    ws2.Cells.AutoFilter

    ws2.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Years & "-" & Months & "-" & Days
    MIN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws2.Range("D2:D1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ws.Cells(R, 11).Value = MIN
    ws2.Cells.AutoFilter
```

As you can see, I use the variable "R" to address the row number. I'll have close to 50 more "else If" function.

I want to have like a "MAIN" function, then I place the "FOR-NEXT" function then the "IF-ELSE", but the only procedure inclusive to the "IF-ELSE" function is the "CALL" Function.

But the variable "R" won't work anymore. And I don't know how to match the "R" in the "IF ELSE" function to the next SUB.

Hope someone can understand this long post. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the issue properly, but wouldn't declaring the R variable as a Public variable solve your issue?

Comment: Are you resetting the variable, so it starts at R = 10 each time you call the macro?

Comment: Could you explain what the code is meant to do - I can see you're filtering to a date in column A on different sheets (`ws1` & `ws2`) if the bank name and identifier are correct in columns B and C on the first sheet (`ws`).  You're then summing the filtered values in column E & D to place on your first sheet.  It looks like you should just be passing the _bank name_, _identifier_, _date_ and _worksheet reference_ to a separate procedure or maybe a function that would return an array of two numbers containing your sums.

Comment: Do not forget you can use parameters when writing `Sub` or `Function`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to filter - you could use `SUMIF`.

The `ReturnMyNumbers` function in the below example add the numbers from columns `E` & `K` based on the date in column `A`.  It then returns both numbers to the calling procedure.
I've included the *bank name* and *identifier* to the function arguments - I'm not sure how you use these on deciding which sheet to add up from, so thought I'd leave them in there.

The `Test` procedure is where you'd step through your rows on `ws` passing the arguments to the function on each iteration of the loop.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyResults As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Can put results directly into cells.
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B1") = ReturnMyNumbers( _
            Bank:="Asia United Bank", _
            Account:="C/A# 001-01-002838-0", _
            AccountSheet:=.Worksheets("Sheet2"), _
            ActiveDate:=DateSerial(2018, 9, 13))

        'Or pass results back to variable.
        MyResults = ReturnMyNumbers("Asia United Bank", "C/A# 001-01-002838-0", .Worksheets("Sheet3"), DateSerial(2019, 4, 15))
        'And then paste into cells.
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2") = MyResults
        'Or use the two results separately.
        MsgBox MyResults(0) & " and " & MyResults(1)

    End With

End Sub

Public Function ReturnMyNumbers(Bank As String, Account As String, _
    AccountSheet As Worksheet, ActiveDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim Add As Double
    Dim Min As Double

    With AccountSheet
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        Add = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("A1", rLastCell), ActiveDate, .Range(.Cells(1, 5), rLastCell.Offset(, 5)))
        Min = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("A1", rLastCell), ActiveDate, .Range(.Cells(1, 11), rLastCell.Offset(, 11)))
    End With

    ReturnMyNumbers = Array(Add, Min)

End Function
```